# How to get relative time from a string?

Tags: python, datetime

A user will input, for example `7d 5m 4w` or `7min` or `6h` etc. as a string, but how do I convert that into a datetime object which I will use for a timer.
I have tried using

```
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str, "%M %H %d %m")
```

but that gives me a spesific time, not a length. If a user inputs "35min" or "35m" `time` should be the time right now + 1min

Comment: You will need to calculate the difference (minus operator) between a starting time and an ending time (or "now").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract two `datetime` objects. The result is a `datetime.timedelta` object:

```
started = datetime.datetime.now()

str = "20 12 01 01 2019"
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str, "%M %H %d %m %Y")

diff = time - started

print(str(diff))
print(diff.total_seconds())
```

This is the output:

```
121 days, 0:52:12.768755
10457532.768755
```

---

Based on your comment:

```
datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
```

creates a `datetime.datetime` object shifting `now` by one hour.

---

This is a simpler approach: `time.time()` measures seconds (as float) since 1.1.1970. So if you want to do some work for 0.1 second you can write:

```
import time

started = time.time()
while time.time() < started + 0.1:
    print("do some work")
```

To parse user input to extract the required seconds using `datetime.datetime.strptime` only works if your user follows the specified format. Else you might better implement your own parser for this.

Comment: That is not what I meant, my question was probably too vague. I meant if a user inputs "7h", time will be the time right now + 7h